# Partitioning binary strings by total parity

Tags: combinatorics, binary

If I have a binary string $\underline{a} = (a_1 \, a_2 \,\ldots\, a_N)$ where $a_i \in 0,1$ and I partition the set of all such strings $A$ by the total parity of the string, $A = \Pi_0 + \Pi_1$ where $\Pi_0$ and $\Pi_1$ are the subset of strings with total parity 0 and 1 respectively
$$ \textrm{i.e.   } \left( \sum_k a_k \right) \textrm{ mod } 2 = p \textrm{  for all  } \underline{a} \in \Pi_p \, , $$
is the function where I change the value of the first element, 
$$ M[\, \underline{a} \,] = M[\, (a_1 \, a_2 \,\ldots\, a_N) \,] = (\overline{a_1} \, a_2 \,\ldots\, a_N) \,, $$
a bijection between the two subsets, $ M : \Pi_0 \rightarrow \Pi_1$?

Comment: Isn't it obviously so? It is self-inverse, hence a bijection, and sends every string to a string of opposite parity.

Comment: I think so, I'd appreciate some help writing a proof though. I think it should be different for the case where N is even and odd too. My intuition is it should only work if N is odd because there would be a different number of elements in Pi0 and Pi1 if N was even.

Comment: N even/odd seems simply irrelevant. 2^N is always even.

Comment: You could prove a lemma: if f:X->X is a bijective self map and A,B is a partition of X with f(A) \subseteq B and f(B) \subseteq A, then |A| = |B|.

Comment: In the case N is odd I can prove |P0| = |P1| -- let F(a1...aN) = (~a1...~aN), this clearly is a bijection from P0 <-> P1, then since this bijection exists |P0| = |P1| -- But in the case N is even F:P0 -> P0 and F:P1 -> P1

Comment: Whether or not N is even plays a role in whether or not the F in your last comment is a bijection, but the bijection in your original question works in both the even and odd cases. It *is* a bijection, and it flips the parity of its input. Little more needs to be said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a bijection,

- each element of X must be paired with at least one element of Y, and each element of Y must be paired with at least one element of X,

  - $M(\underline{a}) $ always maps to an element in the other partition
- no element of X may be paired with more than one element of Y, and no element of Y may be paired with more than one element of X.

  - $M(M(\underline{a}))= \underline{a}$ guarantees a unique partner in the other partition, since every element is recovered by a second application of the function (no loss of domain)